# advanced where in collection (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

Why it doesn't work?

```
  public function getActualNameAttribute() {
      return $this->unit->names->where('valid_from','<=',date('Y-m-d'))->where(function ($query) { $query->where('valid_to','>=',date('Y-m-d'))->orWhereNull('valid_to'); });

    }
```

the expected where should be:

```
WHERE valid_from<='2022-10-27' AND (valid_to>='2022-10-27' OR valid_to IS NULL)
```

but it looks like `where(function($query) ...` doesn't work at all...

Result of $this->unit->names;

```
    [{"id":7,"unit_id":1,"name":"past name","valid_from":"2015-01-26","valid_to":"2021-12-31"},
{"id":81,"unit_id":1,"name":"future name","valid_from":"2023-01-01","valid_to":null},
{"id":80,"unit_id":1,"name":"current_name","valid_from":"2022-01-01","valid_to":"2022-12-31"}]
```

Comment: You are running in the context of `$this->unit->names` which means you are working with a collection, not a query. Collection: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections
Eloquent(query):  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent

Comment: If you want to use it like a query, you could use `names()->` the parenthesis returns the query builder in stead of collection, but this might cause a query n+1 problem

Comment: @Techno I think that it should be collection!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed - changing names to names() (and adding first at the ending) changes everything. I don't understand why - but works...

```php
public function getActualNameAttribute() {
     return $this->unit->names()
               ->where('valid_from','<=',date('Y-m-d'))
               ->where(function ($query) {
                              $query->where('valid_to','>=',date('Y-m-d'))
                              ->orWhereNull('valid_to');
                              })
               ->first();         
}
```

Comment: It's fairly simple. If you don't use `()` at the end, laravel will load the relation as is, and return the collection. If you use `()`, it will return the relationship. It's generally triggered by php's magic method __get https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php